# Is there a command for bysorting 2 variables?

Tags: statistics, stata

Generate a variable for the total number of cards (red+yellow) given to
each player and each season in the dataset.

I thought of using the following code:

```
bysort season: egen sumcards1 = max(red_card)
bysort season: egen sumcards1 = max(yellow_card)
gen total_card = sumcards1 + sumcards2
```

However, that will only `bysort season` only not players. How can I do both?

Comment: This seems very doable but I am not sure I get the details. Can you provide a small data set (using `dataex` in Stata) to show us what you have and what variables you want.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want

```
bysort season player: egen wanted = total(red_card + yellow_card)
```